# extract a string from two indicated strings from a string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I need to extract a string by judging two indicated strings from a long string in C#, e.g. there is a string

```
"weight: 30 pounds. Height: 2 meters."
```

I need to extract the string `"30"` by judging that its front is `"weight: "` and its behind is `" pounds"`. I cannot use index as I have many strings like this to read. Sometimes the weight can be 100 pounds which makes the extraction from index incorrect. How to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Is there something that's always there? I mean, is it always "weight: x pounds."? Then regexps or just substrings with indices from the string will work.

Comment: Thanks. it is always "weight: x pounds." However the length of x can vary. There are many parameters written in one string and I just need to extract one value from one parameter.